# How to know how many people are connected to Firebase in Android studio?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

pretty straightforward question. im making an android app that uses firebase authentication for users to connect with email and password an also the firebase realtime database service.

i wanted to know if i can check through android studio how many people are currently connected to my database(through Firebase Authentication)

thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a sample present system in the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple. Every time a user is connecting to your app, add him in a Firebase category, named `users`. Then you can query on that category to see the exact number of users using the following line of code:

```
int numberOfUsers = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
```

Comment: i basically want to know how many people are playing the game right now, and all of the players who play are connected to firebase. so how do i know when to remove them?( i only need to remove them if the entire app is closed and they stopped playing)..

Comment: There 2 different things. One is, how many players are connected to Firebase and second how many players are connected to Firebase and are playing at the same time. So, in order to answer the second question, because for the first you have the answer above, you need to create another filed in your database named `onlineStatus` in which you'll got to put `true` if the player is `online` and `false` if it's not. You'll need also to put on that field a `ValueEventListener` to see in real time which is the status of the playes and to take action accordingly .

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but in case someone is searching for a solution, I've found some info on Firebase docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence

Answer (score 0):

```
var database = firebase.database();

//   connecting users
var connectionsRef = database.ref("/connections");

var connectedRef = database.ref(".info/connected");
// Number of online users is the number of objects in the presence list.

// When the client's connection state changes...
connectedRef.on("value", function(snap) {

    // If they are connected..
    if (snap.val()) {

        // Add user to the connections list.
        var con = connectionsRef.push(true);

        // Remove user from the connection list when they disconnect.
       con.onDisconnect().remove();
    }
});

// When first loaded or when the connections list changes...
connectionsRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {

    // Display the viewer count in the html.
    // The number of online users is the number of children in the connections list.
    console.log("numers of players are:"+ snapshot.numChildren());
    $(".displayDiv").text(snapshot.numChildren());
```